# Enforce Https with cloud endpoints Framework v2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am currently using cloud endpoints framework on an Appengine application.

Is it possible to enforce Https protocol for exposed endpoints?
Now, I am able to call my endpoints in https but also in http.
I wonder if we can set a redirection to Https like we can in appengine with the "transport-guarantee" set to CONFIDENTIAL.

As an example when I call the drive API on Http, I get the following message

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "sslRequired",
            "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation."
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation."
}
```

}

I would like to have the same behavior with cloud endpoint framework.

Subsidiary questions I found no way to also set HTST on cloud endpoint framework whereas Google is promoting it. 
Did I misunderstand something?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Endpoints Frameworks, that's just a code library for doing API policy enforcement (API keys, rate limiting, etc.), which means Endpoints is only involved *after* an HTTPS or HTTP connection has been established.

Since you're running your API on App Engine, I'd recommend trying to [make your AppEngine app HTTPS-only](https://googlecloud.tips/tips/028-secure-your-app-engine-app-deployment-by-default/).